# Basemap Orthographic Projection - Color Bleeding

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, orthographic

I'm trying to use basemap to plot data onto an orthographic projection. For some reason, the colour runs past the edges on the top right corner. Any advice on how to avoid this?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import random

data = np.zeros([360,720],float)

for i in range(0,360):
    for j in range(0,720):
        if random.random() < 0.9:
            data[i,j] = random.randint(20,30)
        else:
            data[i,j] = random.randint(10,15)

lons = np.arange(-180,180,0.5)
lats = np.arange(-90,90,0.5)

m = Basemap(projection = 'ortho',lon_0 = -95,lat_0 = 75,resolution = 'l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()

lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x,y = m(lons, lats)

my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
my_cmap.set_under('white')
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,cmap = my_cmap)

m.colorbar(cs, extend = 'min')
plt.show()
```

I've provided an image to show what the problem is here:

[Orthographic Projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Dll.png)

Comment: Can you please provide some mock data?  It's not possible to reproduce the problem with the above example.

Comment: Hi, randomized sample data has been added.

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with `Basemap`, see here: https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/207.  Their suggestion is to use `pcolor` instead but the issue is still open.  Perhaps posting your example on the github page would be useful too.

Comment: pcolor seems to work well for me. Thanks!